# Animation in UITextField delegate method does not execute

Tags: objective-c, iphone

When I click on text box `txtAge`, the delegate method gets called but animation does not execute:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSLog(@"field Edited");
    if (textField.tag == 0) {
        NSLog(@"IF Block ");
        [UIPickerView beginAnimations:nil  context:nil];
        [UIPickerView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        PkrView .frame = CGRectMake(0, 450, 414, 215);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@" else");
    }
    return; }
```

Can you figure out why?

Comment: Welcome to Facebook, don't use xcode tag for non-Xcode IDE related questions. Can you please rephrase your question? You definitely missed a lot of stuff here.

Comment: Take some time to read  [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You missed `commitAnimations` call. However, quoted from Apple documentation about `beginAnimations`:

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

You should convert your animation like the following:

```
[UIPickerView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 450, 414, 215);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // optional, do something after animation completed
}];
```